# Include javascript file to JSP file

Tags: java, jsp

Anyone knows on how to include a .js file to a JSP file in java. I can't use the script.js file in JSP. Below is the folder structure of the .js file.

```
+---src
|   \---main              
|       \---webapp
|           |   index.jsp  
|           +---js
|           |       script.js
|           |       
|           +---META-INF
|           |       context.xml
|           |       
|           \---WEB-INF
|                   web.xml
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you get any errors? check the browser's dev tools console

Comment: ... how are you *trying* to use it?

Comment: There is no error. But i already got the answer. Thanks. For flexibility. I use.  <script language="javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/script.js"></script>

Answer (score 3):

put this in the `<head>` along with your other JS includes and CSS.  These types of includes work the same was as static HTML pages, there isn't anything special about your file being JSP in regards to this.

```
<script src="/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: please accept my answer if you feel i have properly answered your question.